# Why is text file showing data in String format even if wrote a byte array to file in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, byte

I am running below code to write byte array to text file  but when I open my text file data    is  shown in String format

```
  File file = new File ("my.xml");        
  String xml =   MyClass.getContentsOfFile(file);
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("data.txt");

  byte [] mybytearray = xml.getBytes();

  fos.write(mybytearray);fos.close();
```

Comment: what are the contents of the `.xml`?

Comment: What do you mean "showing data"?  A file doesn't "show" anything -- it is "shown" by whatever tool you use to inspect it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because everything is bytes. Even strings. The difference is that the sequence of bytes used to represent a string differ according to the encoding you chose.

Which is why it is important, when you read *or* write text, to specify which encoding you want to use.

Note that in your case you don't select an encoding at all, which means the JVM default is used. And this is not portable since different JVMs use different encodings.

Comment: And a sensible default to UTF-8 (I think) will only come with JDK 1.9!

Comment: Thank you for the answer.So what method you suggest to get readable byte array in text file. google's Protocol buffer?

Comment: It should show bytes not string (bytes are shown in numbers)

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand; what do you mean by "show bytes"?

Comment: bytes such as array of numbers?

Comment: So you want a hexdump, basically? That is another problem entirely

Comment: not really..may be I was confused .I just wanted confirmation that whenever I will pull my data from data.txt it will be in byte array format I think I got my answer.